# How to hide side panel in Nautilus by default?

Tags: nautilus, 16.10

Is there any setting that allows me to hide left side panel on Nautilus by default?

I know it remembers the setting during the user session but I still have to hide it every time I login.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a setting for it in 14.04, but I am not sure about 16.10. Nautilus has changed a lot in recent years.

Try

```
gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-sidebar
```

the output should be `true`, when the sidebar is visible, or false, when not.

To hide the sidebar, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-sidebar false
```

Needless to say, it should now be trivial to unhide it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-sidebar true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just additional info based on @mikewhatever's answer if somebody wants quick toggle solution. You can create following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ISON="$(gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-sidebar)";
if [ "$ISON" = true ]; then
    gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-sidebar false;
else
    gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-sidebar true;
fi
```

Then make it executable and you can create alias in `~/.bash_aliases' as following:

```
alias nsp='~/path/to/created/file/nautilus-sidepanel.sh'
```

Instead of `nsp` you can name it whatever you want (of course no spaces etc), then after saving it, run `source ~/.bashrc` in terminal. After that you can toggle the nautilus side panel just by running `nsp` command.

You can also create custom keyboard shortcut just by placing the link to the file as a command.